# Error While installing Ruby on rails

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ruby-on-rails

I am consulted this [document (How To Install Rails and nginx with Passenger on Ubuntu)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu). Currently i am using `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`. This time i am first installing ruby with rails.. how can i fixed this problem ??

```
rvm install 2.3.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system.
Installing required packages: libyaml-dev, sqlite3, libgmp-dev, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev...
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libyaml-dev sqlite3 libgmp-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1465971805_ruby-2.3.1/package_install_libyaml-dev_sqlite3_libgmp-dev_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev.log
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package libncurses5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libtinfo-dev

E: Unable to locate package libyaml-dev
E: Unable to locate package sqlite3
E: Unable to locate package libgmp-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgdbm-dev
E: Package 'libncurses5-dev' has no installation candidate
++ return 100
++ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are some dependencies missing.  Run `apt-get update` and check for the dependencies that give you 404 errors.  Then go to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment those dependencies out.